# Django ошибкa 404

Tags: python, django

Не могу понять в чем ошибка. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Файл `Human\urls.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
#from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

from Human.views import index, get_profession

urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name='Home'),
    path('profession/<int:profession_id>', get_profession, name='profession')
]
```

Файл `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Human, Profession

def index(request):
   human = Human.objects.all()
   professions = Profession.objects.all()
   context = {
      'human': human,
      'title': 'Список',
      'professions': professions
   }
   return render(request, 'Human/index.html', context=context)

def get_profession(request, profession_id):
   human = Human.objects.filter(profession_id=profession_id)
   professions = Profession.objects.all()
   profession = Profession.objects.get(pk=profession_id)
   context = {
      'human': human,
      'professions': professions,
      'profession': profession
   }
   return render(request, 'Human/profession.html', context=context)
```

[image]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Логичный вопрос — файл `Human\urls.py` вообще подключается куда-нибудь как-нибудь?

Comment: Как это проверить?

Comment: Вы должны были самостоятельно написать какой-нибудь код его подключения и абсолютно точно знать, подключали вы его или нет. Если же вы этого не знаете — значит, видимо, вам нужно почитать в уроках/учебниках/документации Django о том, [как работает роутинг](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/urls/)

Comment: Почитал, я просто только что начал изучать python. И все равно не могу понять в чем причина.

Comment: Покажите содержимое urls.py, который лежит в папке проекта

Answer (score 0):

Содержимое Newsproject/urls.py должно быть таким:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('Human.urls')),
]
```

т.е в urls.py проекта вы включаете адреса приложения. Это стандартная процедура без которой адресация вашего приложения работать не будет.
Сомневаюсь насчет заглавной буквы проекта/приложения...